# Convergence of value iteration

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, iteration, markov-chains, convergence

Why the termination condition of value-iteration algorithm
( example http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/probability/mdp/search/ValueIteration.java )

In the MDP (Markov Desicion Process) is

||Ui+1-Ui||< error*(1-gamma)/gamma, where

Ui is vector of utilities
 Ui+1 updated vector of utilities

error -error bound used in algorithm

gamma-discount factor used in algorithm

Where does "error*(1-gamma)/gamma" come from?
"divided by gamma" is because every step is discounted by gamma?
But error*(1-gamma)? 
And how big must be an error?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, especially "What is MDP?" and "What are your parameters (the Ui, gamma, error, etc)?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called a Bellman Error or a Bellman Residual.

See [Williams and Baird](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.3281), 1993 for use in MDPs.

See [Littman](ftp://ftp.cs.brown.edu/pub/techreports/94/cs94-40.pdf), 1994 for use in POMDPs.

Comment: I do not see any references to error*(1-gamma)/gamma termination condition there.

Comment: Theorem three of Littman; taken from the performance bounds section of Williams and Baird.